# Why am I getting this error with laravel websocket library?

Tags: laravel-5, websocket

am trying to set up a web sockets server using laravel 5.7 and keep getting this error

> Argument 2 passed to
>   BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\App::__construct() must be of the
>   type string, null given, called in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/api.cs/vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Apps/ConfigAppProvider.php
>   on line 63 [screenshot missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1E7.png)

....i don't know what to do please help. I'm actually using this guide https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/

Comment: Oooh I GOT IT!!! I just ran the following commands 'php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache' and wolah!! I figured it out I did run a migration but didn't refresh the cache <Im using multiple databases> so the cache needed to be flushed first. I've been doing so every time I make a new database

Comment: You can [post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cache:
Run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Or

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

After running migration use the following sequence of commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I forgot to install `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`

which resulted in so many errors while it was working just fine except for the errors, after installing all errors fixed